# Can I setup KVM Hypervisor on Soft Raid?

Tags: virtualization, centos7, kvm-virtualization, dedicated-server, hypervisor

I'm running several virtual private servers as well as quite a few dedicated machines. I'm wanting to cut costs by setting up a dedicated server to run enough virtual servers to meet my requirements. I'm considering getting a Virtualizor license and setting up KVM.

I spoke with one of my datacenter's helplines and they informed me that I may run into issues running hypervisor software on a soft raid. I'm comfortable enough with hardware and sysadmin to get by but this was news to me.

Is there any validity to their claim and if so, what can I do (or should I use) to overcome it (besides looking for a new host)?

Comment: What issues did they say you would run into?

Comment: "Incompatibility issues" is all they said. I also contacted Virtualizor (after making this post) to ask them. They informed me lots of people run it on Soft Raid but there may be some speed concerns as the Raid will use CPU power to sync the data.

Comment: Performance might be an issue on ancient hardware, but these days you're unlikely to notice without synthetic benchmarks.

Comment: Understood. I'm going for NVMe drives, latest CPUs, the works. So good intel, thank you!